# How do I encode "&" in a URL in an HTML attribute value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'd like to make a URL click able in the email app.  The problem is that a parameterized URL breaks this because of "&" in the URL.  The body variable below is the problem line.  Both versions of "body" are incorrect.  Once the email app opens, text stops at "...link:".  What is needed to encode the ampersand?

```
NSString *subject = @"This is a test";
NSString *encodedSubject = 
[subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

//NSString *body = @"This is a link: <a href='http://somewhere.com/two.woa/wa?id=000&param=0'>click me</a>"; //original
NSString *body = @"This is a link: <a href='http://somewhere.com/two.woa/wa?id=000&#38;param=0'>click me</a>"; //have also tried &amp;
NSString *encodedBody = 
[body stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSString *formattedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"mailto:myname@somedomain.com?subject=%@&body=%@", encodedSubject, encodedBody];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:formattedURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the ampersand would be %26 for HEX in [URL Encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) standards

Answer (score 11):

I've been using `-[NSString gtm_stringByEscapingForURLArgument]`, which is provided in [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/), specifically in [GTMNSString+URLArguments.h](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BURLArguments.h) and [GTMNSString+URLArguments.m](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BURLArguments.m).

Comment: FYI, you'll need these four files to get it to work:
GTMDefines.h
GTMGarbageCollection.h
GTMNSString+URLArguments.h
GTMNSString+URLArguments.m

Comment: It's easy to write a version that doesn't user their garbage collection if you change the return to `return [(NSString *)escaped autorelease];`.

Comment: @keegan3d and if you're using ARC , you can change return to `return (__bridge NSString *)escaped;`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hex representation of the character, in this case %26.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` with `CFBridgingRelease` for **ARC** support

```
NSString *subject = @"This is a test";
// Encode all the reserved characters, per RFC 3986
// (<http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt>)
NSString *encodedSubject =
(NSString *) CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                            (CFStringRef)subject,
                                            NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, exactly like you are doing.

The problem is that you aren't using it enough. The format into which you're inserting the encoded body *also* has an ampersand, which you have not encoded. Tack the unencoded string onto it instead, and encode them (using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`) together.

Comment: Wasn't really sure what you meant.

Comment: The format string you're passing to stringWithFormat: has an unencoded ampersand in it. stringWithFormat: won't escape it and your existing stringByAddingPercentEscapes message won't work backwards upon it.

Comment: I would rearrange the code so that you send stringByAddingPercentEscapes to the string you got from stringWithFormat:. The other way would be to escape it in the format string literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='http://somewhere.com/two.woa/wa?id=000&#38;param=0'>click me</a>
```

Is correct, although ‘&amp;’ is more commonly used than ‘&#38;’ or ‘&#x2C;’.

If the ‘stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding’ method does what it says on the tin, it should work(*), but the NSString documentation looks a bit unclear on which characters exactly are escaped. Check what you are ending up with, the URL should be something like:

```
mailto:bob@example.com?subject=test&body=Link%3A%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A//example.com/script%3Fp1%3Da%26amp%3Bp2%3Db%22%3Elink%3C/a%3E
```

(*: modulo the usual disclaimer that mailto: link parameters like ‘subject’ and ‘body’ are non-standard, will fail in many situations, and should generally be avoided.)

> Once the email app opens, text stops at "...link:".

If ‘stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding’ is not escaping ‘<’ to ‘%3C’, that could be the problem. Otherwise, it might not be anything to do with escapes, but a deliberate mailer-level restriction to disallow ‘<’. As previously mentioned, ?body=... is not a reliable feature.

In any case, you shouldn't expect the mailer to recognise the HTML and try to send an HTML mail; very few will do that.

Comment: This was tagged as an iPhone question, and HTML mail works fine with iPhone Mail.

Comment: Yep - HTML mail works fine.  I use it all the time.  The problem is in the URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Example of use of %26  instead of & without this attributes arrived in PHP as an array!

```
    var urlb='/tools/lister.php?type=101%26ID='+ID; // %26 instead of &
    window.location.href=urlb;
```