# Creating an mailto: URL with a URL in the body iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, url, escaping, mailto

UPDATE: I just found a similar post here:
[How do I encode "&" in a URL in an HTML attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730101/how-do-i-encode-in-a-url-in-an-html-attribute-value)

Please consider the code below:
I try to send an email message from within my iPhone app.
The problem I encounter is that I want to put a URL in the body of the email.
This URL contains two ampersands.
I am encoding all the strings using "stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding", but the URL ends up in my new mail messagd truncated after the first ampersand. IE: "http://www.mydomain.nl/?cm=79&ctime=1246572000&cid=4772" becomes "http://www.mydomain.nl/?cm=79".

Any suggestion what I could do to escape?

```
 NSString *eMailSubject = @"My Subject";
 NSString *encodedSubject = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[eMailSubject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
 NSString *eMailBody = @"http://www.mydomain.nl?cm=79&ctime=1246572000&cid=4772";
 NSString *encodedBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[eMailBody stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
 NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?subject=%@&body=%@", encodedSubject, encodedBody]];
 NSString *encodedURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:encodedURL];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the body of the email message HTML? If so, most email readers and browsers will try to interpret the ampersand as an HTML entity prefix and seeing 'ctime' instead of a legal entity value following the ampersand, just give up on parsing the rest of the string.

[Here are some details](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp). Try doing a string substitution of the '`&`' characters with '`&amp;`' and see if that helps.

Also, might want to consider using the new messaging framework in OS 3.0 that allows you to send email directly from inside your app.

Comment: The problem here is that the substitution of "&" contains an "&", so that doesn't solve the problem.
As suggested here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730101/how-do-i-encode-in-a-url-in-an-html-attribute-value) I should use the hex code %26. Somehow that is not working for me either.

Comment: You're mixing up the "&" in a URL with "&" as an HTML entity. The %26 value is for encoding it in a URL. But if you want to include a link in HTML content you need to substitute "&" with "&amp;". When the HTML parser sees the "&" it looks ahead at what follows. If it's one of the legal entity values in the link I posted, then it renders it with that character. If it's invalid then it stops (which is what you're getting). Check the section on ampersands here: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want real HTML URLs you can't use the `mailto:`.

You have to do one of the following:

1. implement your own SMTP server
2. use SDK 3.0 mail framework (MFMailCompose...)

Comment: That is quite a statement! Do you have some argumentation for it?

Comment: mostly trial and error.  

In the iPhone 2.2 days, I released some code to do the smtp part.  it's avalable at: http://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp/tree